# How to keep an absolute path unchanged for a script tag in index.html with Vite

Tags: javascript, html, vite, rollupjs

With Vite, using absolute paths in `index.html` results in them being transformed based on the `base` config, which is nice.

For instance my `index.html` contains this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/config.js"></script>
```

And `base` is set to "/demo". The exported `index.html` will contain:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/demo/config.js"></script>
```

This is fine for most of my file but I would need to have a script loaded from the root of the server for a very specific thing. Is it possible to indicate to Vite to not change the path of a specific script tag? Like a preprocessor command? Like this:

```html
<!-- @vite-ignore -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/config.js"></script>
```

That would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an ugly fix:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // We have to do it using javascript otherwise Vite modifies the path
      var config = document.createElement('script')
      config.type = 'text/javascript'
      config.src = '/config.js'
      document.head.appendChild(config)
    </script>
```